# How can I get my facebook friends' and their friends' like history in FOAF structure?

Tags: facebook, rdf, semantic-web, foaf

I want to generate a product recommendation system using facebook FOAF data. Can any body tell me how can I get the "like" history of my friends and their friends in FOAF structure?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: You can't. Starting with Graph API v2.0, you cannot access the friend information anymore, because Fb deprecated all the `friends_*` permissions.

Comment: Thank you sir. Actually I need to make a product recommendation system from facebook like history using Semantic web approach for my college project. I have my own recommendation algorithm. But no idea to implement it in semantic approach. So can you please suggest me how can I implement it or give me any tutorial on this matter?

Comment: What part of "You can't" didn't you understand? Access to Facebook data is permission-based...